# Highlight Row-Column of selected cell

Tags: vba, excel, highlight

Be gentle guys, I'm not a programmer.

I got this snippit of code off the internet many many moons ago.  I would give credit, but I don't remember where it came from.

```
Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
Static xRow
Static xColumn
If xColumn <> "" Then
With Columns(xColumn)
.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
End With
With Rows(xRow)
.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
End With
End If
pRow = Selection.Row
pColumn = Selection.Column
xRow = pRow
xColumn = pColumn
With Columns(pColumn)
.Interior.ColorIndex = 19
.Interior.Pattern = xlSolid
End With
With Rows(pRow)
.Interior.ColorIndex = 19
.Interior.Pattern = xlSolid
End With
End Sub
```

The above code highlights rows and columns of a selected sell.  The problem is that it highlights columns from 1 to 1048576, which causes the vertical scroll bar to get tiny.  Plus if there is any color coding in the spreadsheet it screws that up.  I decided to write my own highlighter.  I put a border around my selected row,column and only do it for 500 rows.  It works, almost.  The problem is that something in my code cancels the copy command, and will not allow me to paste, which did not happen in the code above.  Copy/Paste is a must.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
Range("A1:N500").Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Weight = xlThin
Range("A1:N500").Borders(xlEdgeTop).Weight = xlThin
Range("A1:N500").Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlThin
Range("A1:N500").Borders(xlEdgeRight).Weight = xlThin
Range("A1:N500").Borders(xlInsideVertical).Weight = xlThin
Range("A1:N500").Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).Weight = xlThin
Range("A1:N500").Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Color = vbBlack
Range("A1:N500").Borders(xlEdgeTop).Color = vbBlack
Range("A1:N500").Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Color = vbBlack
Range("A1:N500").Borders(xlEdgeRight).Color = vbBlack
Range("A1:N500").Borders(xlInsideVertical).Color = vbBlack
Range("A1:N500").Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).Color = vbBlack
Dim SplitAddress() As String
SplitAddress = Split(ActiveCell.Address, "$")
Dim RowSelection As String
RowSelection = "A" & SplitAddress(2) & ":" & "N" & SplitAddress(2)
Dim ColSelection As String
ColSelection = SplitAddress(1) & "1" & ":" & SplitAddress(1) & "500"
With Range(RowSelection)
.BorderAround Weight:=xlThick, Color:=RGB(255, 0, 0)
End With
With Range(ColSelection)
.BorderAround Weight:=xlThick, Color:=RGB(255, 0, 0)
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: "The problem is that it highlights columns from 1 to 1048576, which causes the vertical scroll bar to get tiny."  That shouldn't happen because of that code, and doesn't when I run the code.  (Scroll bars are only affected by how far down the sheet I go.)

Comment: If the column is highlighted, Excel thinks there is content in it.  Which shrinks the scroll.

Comment: As I said, it doesn't when I run that code.  The scroll bars should be based on what Excel thinks is the viewed range, so should only extend to how far down the sheet you have travelled, or to the end of the `UsedRange`, whichever is the greater.  (If the code only highlighted a certain number of rows within the column, that would affect `UsedRange`, but as long as the whole column is having its `Interior` changed, the `UsedRange` is left untouched.)

Comment: Maybe I have a different version of Excel or Windows.  But that doesn't matter.  This is tangential to my question.  Why does the first block of code not affect copy and paste, yet the second one does?

Answer (score 0):

try this.

it is work in progress

it copies the format, as the default format, from the very last cell in worksheet

the code uses no copy/paste to do the borders

i am still working on copy/paste between cells that you are having trouble with

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim aaa As DisplayFormat
    Set aaa = Range("XFD1048576").DisplayFormat   ' copy format from very last cell (it is a cheat)

    Range("A1:N500").Borders.Color = aaa.Borders.Color          ' revert border color to its default
    Range("A1:N500").Borders.LineStyle = aaa.Borders.LineStyle

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = xlEdgeLeft To xlEdgeRight   ' loop the four outside borders (7 to 10)
        Target.EntireRow.Resize(1, 8).Borders.Item(i).Color = vbRed
        Target.EntireRow.Resize(1, 8).Borders.Item(i).Weight = xlThick

        Target.EntireColumn.Resize(500, 1).Borders.Item(i).Color = vbRed
        Target.EntireColumn.Resize(500, 1).Borders.Item(i).Weight = xlThick

    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```